# Python Dictionary Spell Checker, 'TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments'

Tags: python, hashtable

I'm using a python dictionary to compare Shakespeares full works and a 10,000 word dictionary, the code should output all words which weren't found in the 10,000 word dictionary to a separate file called 'SpellChecker.txt'. I believe everything in this code is running correctly. I am only coming across one error to do with saving the data to the output file and can't seem to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JakeFrench/Desktop/HashTable.py", line 29, in <module>
    f1.write(word+'\n', encoding= 'utf-8')
```

### TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments

```
import re
import time
start_time = time.time()

f1=open ('SpellChecker.txt', 'w+')

Dictionary = {}
Document = []
with open ('10kWords.txt', encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
        for word in f:
            Dictionary[word.rstrip()] = 1

with open ('ShakespeareFullWorks.txt', encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
    content = f.read().split(" ")
    content = [item.lower() for item in content]
    content = ' '.join(content)
    content = re.findall("\w+", content)
    for line in content:
        Document.append(line)

for line in content:
    for word in line.split():
        if word.lower() not in Dictionary:
            f1.write(word+'\n', encoding= 'utf-8')

f1.close()            

print ("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: remove `encoding='utf-8'` in `.write()

Comment: Hi Hamza, I have already tried that and when I do I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JakeFrench/Desktop/HashTable.py", line 29, in <module>
    f1.write(word+'\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe6' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You should remove the encoding from the write function and set it in the open function instead.

Comment: Thank you very very much! That's worked, looking back at the code now I realise it was quite a silly mistake haha but that's how code is sometimes I guess lol

Comment: No problem, I have added the comment in an answer form just to be  clearer.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!

Comment: Strange, you did that in correctly 2 places....

Comment: Yeah must've just not been thinking hahah, been working on this far too long and far too tired lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the encoding attribute from the `write` method and insert it in the `open` function as follows:

```
f1=open ('SpellChecker.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8')
  ...
f1.write(word+'\n')
```